# testing whether the data is matching upto 4 decimal places using pytest and publish report by using it

Tags: python, pandas, testing, pytest

[image]

I have dataframe as above now I have to match buy with new_perc_buy (upto 4 decimal places) similarly sell with new_perc_sell (upto 4 decimal places) and if it does not meet the decided condition it fails
but for reporting and comparing purpose I wanted to use **pytest** I did not know how to perform it in **pytest** whether there is an assert method for it ?

Comment: Try using numpy's assert function, [assert almost equal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.html).

Comment: @forgetso but how can I get proper testing report  without pytest

Comment: @jezrael can you please help me into this

Answer (score 1):

You can use decimal.Decimal to express the number to a specific number of decimal places and then simply assert in pytest.

```
import decimal

four_decimal= decimal.Decimal('0.0001')

def test():
    # get your data from database or something, if they are currently
    # representing as string, do not convert to float first but use
    # decimal.Decimal right away

    # just to show how to get the specific number of decimal places
    # usually you dont want to go float->decimal if you dont have to
    d = decimal.Decimal(1/3.0).quantize(four_decimal)
    d2 = decimal.Decimal("3214143214214321.3134").quantize(four_decimal)
    d3 = decimal.Decimal(3214143214214321/3).quantize(four_decimal)
    d4 = d2 - d - d3 + d3 + d
    # run with -s to see what's going on
    print(d)
    print(d2)
    print(d3)
    print(d4)
    # and now just assert
    assert d != d2
    assert d2 != 1/3.0
    assert d2 == d4
```

Note that the `quantize` method can also take parameter `rounding` to specify how to round to 4 decimal places only.